# How to use the keras model.fit() function on a dataset with multiple items in its data dictionary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have a custom class for my data generator. It's a TFDS custom dataset.

```
class MyDataset(tfds.core.GeneratorBasedBuilder)
```

my `_generate_samples` function yields a dictionary with multiple different elements.

```
  def _generate_examples(self, path):
    labels_df  = pd.read_csv(Path(os.getcwd())/ 'image-path.csv')
    for image_path in path.glob('*.jpg'):
      ... #some code here to get image name and other attributes from labels_df
      yield image_name, { # name of image is unique
          'image': image_path,
          'labelA': labels_df.loc[(sample_name, object_number), 'a'],
          'labelB': labels_df.loc[(sample_name, object_number), 'b'],
      }
```

When I make a model in keras and call `model.fit` I get the following error:
`ValueError: Missing data for input "efficientnetb0_input". You passed a data dictionary with keys ['species', 'labelA', 'labelB']. Expected the following keys: ['efficientnetb0_input']`

I already have

```
supervised_keys=('image', 'labelA'),
```

in my `_info` function as well. But it's not working. In addition, I'm wondering if there's a way to specify it in the `model.train` function (or some kind of tfds dataset transformation or function) so that I can do supervised learning on both labelA and labelB at some point.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to yield image and two label as tuples? So it will be something like this
`yield (image, (label_a, label_b))`. And also if you want to fed the neural network straight with that generator, the image should be not the path but the image array it self instead

Comment: Good catch on the image path vs the array!
And about the labels--how would I do this if I only wanted the network to be trained only on label_a, for example?